# Using Java 8 Streams how to get two different list using one list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assume i have list of employee's data.

```
class Employee {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int age;
   // Constrctor
   // setters & getters
}
List<Employee> empList = ...;
```

Using above empList, how to get two different lists like **age > 20** into one list and **age < 20** into one list using **Java8 streams**.

Comment: plese show us your effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What should happen to **age = 20** elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Collectors.partitioningBy`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(new Employee(10), new Employee(15),
            new Employee(21), new Employee(22));

    Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> employeeGroups = employeeList.stream().
                    collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.getAge() > 20));

    System.out.println(employeeGroups.get(false));
    System.out.println(employeeGroups.get(true));
}
```

***Output:***

```
[Employee{age=10}, Employee{age=15}]
[Employee{age=21}, Employee{age=22}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> ageGtThan20ToEmployees = empList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.age > 20));
System.out.println("Employees 20 years old are: "+ageGtThan20ToEmployees.get(true));
```

Comment: Better use the boolean-specialized`partitioningBy`. Not only for efficiency, it also guarantees that `geGtThan20ToEmployees.get(true)` will never be `null`.

Comment: @Holger and that change were introduced because of a discussion on Stackoverflow if I remember following few links correctly. Aside: Since this question revolves around `partitioning`, I have been recently wondering why would there be a need for `List.of` and not `Set.of` while returning the iterator from `entrySet()` within the `Partition` implementation of `Collectors`. (or `Arrays.asList` prior to JDK-9). Does the order(false, true) really matter?

Comment: @Naman the behavior was always like this, but the documentation lacked a statement that it is intentional, which had been added after a discussion on Stackoverflow (some discussed optimizations are still missing). The natural order [false, true] might be another undocumented intentional feature. But it could also be just a performance consideration, as the `Set.of` factory contains a check for duplicates which is obsolete here (the set and list iterators for two elements are almost the same).

Comment: @Holger Thank you. This was what I was looking for. I've tried looking for iterator implementations and differences there, meanwhile overlooking the creation of the Collection on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it simple using `filter`:

```
List<Employee> greater20 = empList.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getAge() > 20).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Employee> smaller20 = empList.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getAge() < 20).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
List<Employee> greaterThan20 = empList.filter(e -> e.age > 20).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Employee> lessThan20 = empList.filter(e -> e.age < 20).collect(Collectors.toList());
```